# Dell vostro-3550 does not boot from ODD (second HDD)

Tags: hard-drive, boot, dell-vostro

I have a Dell Vostro 3550, with one HDD SATA in it. I used a caddy to adapt the HDD to use it the place of my CD/DVD-ROM drive.

Q: How can I boot from this new SATA port (ODD/second drive/etc)?

Comment: So, is there an operating system on this second disk?

Comment: This. I just take my HDD, with my working windows 10, and add to the another SATA port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I boot from this drive on the second SATA port?

Simply, either:

1. Go to the firmware (BIOS/EFI) and select the second drive as primary boot drive.  (Some laptops firmware offer very limited fuctionality though, so depending on your motherboard model and firmware version this option might not be present).
2. Remove the old drive from the first SATA connector. That only leaves #2 to boot. (Handy for quick testing, though not quite so useful in the long term).
3. Accept that the system will start to boot from the first disk. Just how it continues after that depends on your bootloader. Chain that to the second disk.